# How can I speed up chlorophyte growth?

Tags: terraria

I've set up a chlorophyte farm and it is growing chlorophyte. Is there a way to speed up its growth? Does anything govern its growth?

Comment: You can grow Cholorphyte?

Comment: Indeed, and it works, but sloooowly. Google "chlorophyte farm".

Comment: Have you placed it deep underground? If so, multiple smaller blocks instead of fewer larger blocks will probably do the trick. You can read about it on the wikia about Chlorophyte. http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Chlorophyte_Ore

Comment: Yeah I read the wiki. As I said, it is growing. But it doesn't seem to be growing very quickly. I left my character running on the server last night and this morning I don't see any new blocks. My only conclusion is that it will grow _up to_ 25 blocks then stop at a random block count.

Comment: A bit of a late note that can help speed up growth; all Jungle Grass is capable of spontaneously converting any mud block within 10 tiles of it to Chlorophyte - while quite rare, it can still help occasionally.

Comment: From personal experience: sometimes the chlorophyte that should have 'grown' does not show up until you reload the map.

Comment: If you have too many seed chlorophyte ores, they can hinder growth. http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Chlorophyte_Ore has the specific numbers. I've done about 14 5x5 blocks in a line, next to my hellavator, and they all grow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The farm has to be in the underground layer or lower, and the chlorophyte will grow at a rate of about 1 ore per hour. Also, it seems that chlorophyte will grow when you kill Plantera, so you can check conditions by killing Plantera and then check the farm.

The farm's layout can affect growth rate, too. [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138248/what-farm-layout-will-produce-the-most-chlorophyte) might be helpful for layout information.

Comment: I left my character logged on last night and there was zero ore growth in all of the the 5x5 blocks (14 total). The farm is at -850 feet. Some ore grew at first (about 30 blocks from 7 seed blocks) but now none will grow. Is it a light problem?

Comment: I saw this problem one more time.it has been solved by removing some of 5*5 squares.so remove some of them and see what happens.

Comment: Do you have a source on Plantera spawning chlorophyte? I don't see it mentioned in the wikis.

Comment: I saw this by myself and some other people experienced it.There is no official source for it.

Comment: I think Plantera's death causes more Chloro to spawn, like a demon altar.

Comment: Plantera's death causes both grow and spawn of chlorophyte.so killing it many times is a good way to get chlorophyte(killing it too much will not break 25-ore limit)

Answer (score 0):

I just made 6 5x5 mud blocks with 1 chlorophyte ore each in the center. The "squares" are 2 blocks away from each other and have 4 torches each. Seems to be working fine..Got about 5 grown ore in less than 5 minutes. I recommend reducing the space in the cave you made around the "squares" because I think it is related to the ore's growth. I tried it twice and got more ore if the space around the cave is narrow.[image]

Comment: This won't work well as there is a limit to how much chlorophyte can be within 100ft